# Upgrading Dell Optiplex 380 with 8GB DDR3 RAM

Tags: dell, operating-system, memory

I've Dell optiplex 380 machine and I've 32bit Windows 7 ultimate OS on it with DDR3 2*2GB RAM on it.

I want to upgrade my machine to use 8GB RAM with 64bit windows 7 ultimate OS and want to install DDR3 2*4GB RAM. Is this possible on this machine?

I'm little bit layman in this area but by reading the specs I have got an impression that max Ram I can use on this machine is 4GB with DDR3 and 8GB with DDR2. Can anybody give me clear idea on this?

specification links of processor and mother board chipset:

[Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/35300/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E5300-%282M-Cache-2_60-GHz-800-MHz-FSB%29)

[Chipset](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/mainstream-chipsets/g41-express-chipset.html)

Comment: Negative voters - if you could give me the reason for downvote, that would help me a lot to reframe my question or give more information.

Comment: this should've been on superuser really, I imagine that's the downvotes, but it was easy to answer so I don't really mind myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on exactly which model of the 380 you have, you didn't include that information.

The small form-fcator version only supports 4GB while the larger models support 8GB.

Have a look [HERE](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listparts.aspx?model=OptiPlex%20380%20Small%20Form%20Factor&Cat=RAM). Oh and this question was really more appropriate for superuser.com but it was very easy to get this answer so that's fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Link which you provided really helped me on this. They gave a downloadable tool which will give me information on upgrading options and that shows that I can use 8GB RAM with 64bit.

Comment: Great news, glad to help :)